# Build with parameters with java 8

Tags: java, gradle, java-8

I use spring, java 8 and gradle.

In Java 8, you can use reflection to access names of parameters of methods. This makes the @Param annotation unnecessary, since Spring can deduce the name of the JPQL parameter from the name of the method parameter.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html

How to do it with gradle

this way i can't build my project

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs = ["-Xlint:unchecked", "-Xlint:deprecation", "–parameters"]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your minus sign in `"–parameters"` is not a "classical" minus sign. Replace it with `"-parameters"`.